# Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. XML is not valid

Tags: wpf

I have two errors in my code:

- Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
- Markup file is not valid. Specify a source markup file with an .xaml extension.

Why?

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApplication.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="Eight Ball Answer" Height="328" Width="412" >
    <Grid Name="grid1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"     Margin="10,10,13,10" Name="txtQuestion"      TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="24"     Grid.Row="0">[Place question here.]</TextBox>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"     Margin="10,0,0,20" Width="127" Height="23" Name="cmdAnswer"     Click="cmdAnswer_Click" Grid.Row="1">Ask the Eight Ball</Button>
        <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"     Margin="10,10,13,10" Name="txtAnswer" TextWrapping="Wrap"     IsReadOnly="True" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="24" Foreground="Green"     Grid.Row="2">[Answer will appear here.]</TextBox>
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.00" Color="Red" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.50" Color="Indigo" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1.00" Color="Violet" />
                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TestWpfApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void cmdAnswer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;            

            txtAnswer.Text = "AAA";
            this.Cursor = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Update 1:

1. This page was created by copy&paste method, not by designer.
2. MainWindow.xaml has property BuildAction set to Page.

Is if helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: The fix is to create a new project and copy over the own stuff.

Your .xaml seems to be valid, are you sure the error is referring to MainWindow.xaml?

Comment: I copied this xaml and cs code behind and it's compiling and working fine. Restart Visual Studio may be the solution

Comment: If a restart does not work you could create a new project and copy over your stuff.

Comment: it's not working in my VSs: 2012Professional ,2015 Online. Any other file s needed for analysis?

Comment: Yes it works after recreating this MainWindow.xaml manually form scratch :).

Comment: Awesome! Can you please accept the answer? Thank you!

Comment: Can you please accept the main answer and not only the comment? Thanks :)

Comment: but we need to knot the root cause of this issue why does it happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

1. Create a xml file Foo.xml
2. Copy the xaml file content to Foo.xml xml file
3. Copy the xaml file name
4. Delete the xaml file

And you should check your csporj file and make sure the new xaml file will be include as Page and compile
1. Rename the Foo.xml xml file name as the xaml file name